# how to align ul list

Tags: html, css

how can i align my lists? what am i doing wrong here?

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/p9C4j/1/

html:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer_content">
  <div class="footer_nav-list">
    <ul class="footer_style_list ">
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Technology</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Customers</a></li>
    </ul>

           <ul class="footer_style_list ">
          <li><a href="#"> Solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">General Descreption</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Detailed Descreption</a></li>
      </ul>

          <ul class="footer_style_list ">
        <li><a href="customers.html">Customers</a>  
          <li><a href="#"> fdhfdhfdhfdh</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Customers List</a></li>
       </ul>

         <ul class="footer_style_list ">
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Call Me Back</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
    <div id="bottom_nav"><span> © 2014</span>
<span>dgfdhfdhdfhdfhl</span>
<span>dfhfdhfdhfdhfdhdfh</span>
<span>fdhfdhdfhdfhhfd.com</span></div><!--close bottom_nav-->

</div></div>
```

Comment: for those who are giving negative votes specify reason

Comment: How are you trying to align your list?

Comment: @laapostos li under li and ul in left of previous ul

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p9C4j/1/ check out

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer_style_list ul {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
}
```

Should be:

```
.footer_style_list {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
}
```

As your `html` is:

```
<ul class="footer_style_list ">
```

You was trying to target `ul` within that `ul`. Made no sense.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/p9C4j/3/)

Note: I'm sure you can sort the rest of the problems.

---

All sorted, read the code and try to make sense of it. I have done very little to it.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/p9C4j/6/)

Comment: it's almost ther but if you notice there is some li that not from the same ul in the lists

Comment: @alonblack Not sure what you mean. Do you mean the fact you have the width to small? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/p9C4j/5/)

Comment: @alonblack Check out the final version [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/p9C4j/6/)

Comment: To the guy who also answered this then deleted it. This is what happens if you try to add more content to the footer. [**Your One**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/p9C4j/7/) and this is the same thing on mine [**my one**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/p9C4j/8/). See how my demo the content is in the correct place and yours its all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

The links are aligned on center due to the following piece of CSS code, namely "text-align: center"

```
.footer_style_list  > li > a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you wish to align left, simply make the following change:

```
text-align: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it commenting some css code

[Your code modified](http://jsfiddle.net/p9C4j/9/)

```
.footer_style_list  > li {

  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  /*height: 30px;*******************/
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #000;
}

.footer_style_list  > li > a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*position: absolute;****************/
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```